# Will usage of LINQ increase day by day or is it that some organizations do not like to use it?

Tags: linq

Will usage of LINQ increase day by day or is it that some organizations do not like to use it?

Comment: Those two things aren't mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq allows you to simplify your code which is always good, as it makes code less fragile and easier to maintain - as long as your intent (as the developer) is clear.

In my experience projects are only light on Linq usage if the development team don't understand the technology fully, or feel that it doesn't fit into their naive views on proper 'OO' architectures and patterns.

Answer (score 0):

This is highly objective and depends on context, but I would say absolutely. If you've built medium sized application both with and without an ORM you will quickly understand the immense benefits LINQ affords. It's hard to imagine an organization building subsequent applications without an ORM in conjunction with LINQ.